# MS SQL ping external server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a 'nice' way to check whether an network host is up
making use of 'plain' SQL? I thought of  some MS-SQL specific
command or maybe some getting the return value from a ping script
on the server itself.

Does anyone has an idea on this?

Comment: The question is: *Why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: My SQL server stores links to content which is provided my an external FTP server. I want my server to check all X minutes whether the ftp box is up, if it's not that run an update and mark the relevant conent as 'temp. not available'.

Comment: Shouldn't this be done in the application layer, instead of the database layer?

Comment: Good point, basically the content is diplayed by java/jsf based web app. Guess it would be an better idea to implement some kind of RegualarRunning class within the app?!

Comment: In the long run this will be a lot more flexible than trying to hack these capabilities into SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two possible ways to take your answer: 
1. you want to know if a SQL server is running on an arbitrary host
2. You want to ping an arbitrary host from a SQL server using some query.

1. you could use dariom's answer. 
   1a. if you want to query one SQL server from another, you're better off using the "Linked Servers" functionality of SQL Server.
2. You can use the [master.dbo.xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(SQL.80).aspx) stored procedure to execute PING, which then returns the results as text rows and a status code.

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'ping 192.168.1.1'

Comment: The status code is not very useful - for me it returns 1 on error and 0 on success. But it returns 0 on "TTL expired in transit", too, so it isn't entirely reliable.

Comment: @Tomalak: unfortunately, that's where you have to analyze the resulting output.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you mean "plain" SQL and not "palin" :-)

If you're trying to see if SQL is running on a host you could try and connect to the [SQL Browser Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) by using the [SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219703(PROT.10).aspx) (but this needs to be installed and running on the server).

You could try a "best guess" approach and make a TCP connection to port 1433 (the default port SQL Server's Database Engine). If the port is open, it might be that a SQL Server is listening - you could then try and connect to SQL Server and execute a command (like `SELECT @@VERSION` or something specific to your application). The problems with this approach:

- SQL Server Database Engine can be configured to use a non-standard TCP port.
- SQL Server might not even be using TCP - you'd have to connect using named pipes (I'm not sure how that's done).
- Some other service could be configured to use TCP port 1433. It doesn't mean that SQL Server is listening.
- If port 1433 is open and used by SQL Server, you'll need to provide credentials to connect to it and execute commands.

Essentially, the best guess approach will only really work with SQL Servers under your control.

Comment: Hi,

thx for your advice! I guess the problem is that i need to check on a FTP box and not an sql server.  thx anyway